# How Do I Block Ads In the Tor browser...?

Tags: browser, tor, noscript

I just started using Tor browser, and there are ads showing up on pretty much every page I've visited.  I've been using Adblocker and Ghostery on my other web browsers for years, so I rarely see ads or flashing gifs anywhere. So, it's a bit annoying to now find all these ads showing up in the Tor Browser.

I've been searching the Tor Blog for a solution, and everyone seems to be saying not to install any addons as they'll compromise your anonymity provided by Tor, and they're also saying ads shouldn't be appearing because NoScript comes installed in the Tor Browser, but I'm seeing ads everywhere.

However, when I uncheck and disable "scripts" in NoScript, it also stops the page I'm viewing from working, so, that's not a solution.

As one example, go to https://www.speedtest.net/ in the Tor browser and there are ads all around the screen. If you disable scripts in Noscript, sure, the ads all disappear, but speedtest no longer works.  In my other browsers, whether I use Adblock or Ghostery all of these ads are all eliminated, but the speed test itself still works. Why isn't this possible to do with the Tor browser...?

Anyone have a solution to eliminating the ads that are showing up in the Tor browser without installing any addons...?

Comment: Be more selective with what you allow. NoScript has more options than just blanket global allow and deny.

Comment: Eliminating ads using adblocker extensions can actually aid browser fingerprinting and therefore tracking. To an extent you are breaking the anonymous "face in a crowd" of anonymous browsing.